# limit_except VS $request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I have been reading quite a bit about **nginx** lately and found 2 approaches online. The first appears to work at the server context level and the second is recommended for the location context level.

**Question.** Is it appropriate to use `limit_except` at the server context level?

**Approach #1** ($request_method) embedded variable

```
# server context
#
# Disable unwanted HTTP methods
# Most of the time, you need just GET, HEAD & POST HTTP request in your web application.
# Allowing TRACE or DELETE is risky as it can allow Cross-Site Tracking attack and potentially
# allow an attacker to steal the cookie information.
# So we return a 405 Not Allowed if someone is trying to use TRACE, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS.

if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$ ) {

  return 405;

}
```

**Approach #2** ([limit_except](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#limit_except)) method

```
# Limits allowed HTTP methods inside a location.
. . .

location /restricted-write {

    # location context

    limit_except GET HEAD {

        # limit_except context

        allow 192.168.1.1/24;
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot use `limit_except` at the `server` context level.  It is only valid within a `location` context, per the [ngx_http_core_module documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#limit_except):

> Syntax:   `limit_except method ... { ... }`
>
> Default:  `—`
>
> Context:  `location`

Approach #1 is the workaround/alternative for similar functionality, with the caveat that your example will give a HTTP status 405 response, instead of the 403 status that `limit_except` will respond with.

Answer (score 0):

Approach #2 can be shortened to

```
limit_except GET {
}
```

`HEAD` will be allowed as per http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#limit_except

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).